# Showing the range of Fourier transform on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ for a particular scenario

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

This is a problem from Katznelson's Harmonic Analysis book(Page 143, Problem 8):

Suppose $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and is continuous at $0$. Also suppose $\hat{f}\geq 0$, then show that $\hat{f}$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ too.

All hints and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the heat kernel. For example, the following holds for all $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$:
$$
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)e^{-s^2t}e^{isx}ds = 
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)e^{-(x-y)^{2}/4t}dy.  
$$
Under your conditions, $\hat{f} \ge 0$ and $f$ is continuous at $0$. Setting $x=0$ gives
$$
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)e^{-s^{2}t}ds
   =\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)e^{-y^{2}/4t}dy
$$
Now, letting $t\downarrow 0$, the right side converges to $f(0)$ because $f$ is continuous at $0$. By the monotone convergence theorem,
$$
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(s)ds = f(0).
$$
The left side is finite because the limit on the right exists.

Comment: can you shed some more light on the identity used to prove the result?

Comment: @Harish : The first expression is the Fourier transform solution of the heat equation $u_{t}=u_{xx}$ obtained by transforming this equation in $x$, and assuming initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$. That's how you get $e^{-ts^{2}}$ into the picture. Then, for $f,g \in L^{1}$, you always have $\int \hat{f}(s)g(s)ds = \int f(y)\hat{g}(y)dx$, which is a good identity to remember. All you have to do is apply with $g(s)=e^{-ts^{2}}e^{-isx}$. Properties of the heat equation give you $u(t,x)\rightarrow f(x)$ as $t\downarrow 0$ if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @T.A.E. There is some problem. In question function $f$ is given to be continuous at $0$. If we assume $f$ continuous everywhere then:
$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)e^{-y^2/4t}\,dt = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\sqrt{t}y)e^{-y^2/4}\,dt$; and since $f$ continuous everywhere and in $L^1$, therefore $\|f\|_{\infty}<\infty$ and hence application of DCT gives $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)e^{-y^2/4t}\,dt = f(0)$.
But if $f$ is given to be continuous only at $0$, how ?

Comment: @T.A.E. Even Theorem 9.9 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis (page 184) requires $f$ to be a bounded function.

Comment: @T.A.E. Ahh things follows without DCT.. Thanks again for the answer :)

Comment: @RakeshBalhara : I assume you straightened out the details? The Gaussian convolution with $f$ at $0$ converges to $f(0)$ if you only require that $f \in L^1$ and is continuous at $0$. And the Fourier transform identity holds very generally. If you have spotted a potential problem, I would be happy to look into it.